# How to prevent zeros from being set when zero values are returned from my Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need some help with Excel.

I have used the simple formula (`=COUNTA(A3:A18)`) equals another cell to pull data to another sheet.

Where it is blank, I do not want the zeros to pull through. I have a count function on the cell highlighted yellow counting the amount of reports and it counts the zeros too which I don't want.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

CountA counts cells that are not blank. Rows 11 and 12 have 0s that why they are also taken into account. If you don't need to count the 0s, you can try the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A3:A18,"<>0",A3:A18,"<>")
```

It counts cells whose values are not 0 and not blank.